# How does tabularray's 'cmd' key work?

Tags: macros, arguments, tabularray

**A demonstration of the issue by way of a minimal working example**

I saved the following LaTeX code in `~/Test.tex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{column{2}={cmd={\bfseries}},column{3}={cmd={\fbox}}}
Hello, world!&Hello, world!&Hello, world!
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The code creates a `tabularray` table having a single row and three columns. The contents of each of the table's three cells are the same: the phrase *Hello, world!*. The command `\bfseries` for using a boldface font, is executed for the 2nd column. The command `\fbox` for drawing the bounding box, is executed for the 3rd column.

I then executed the following commands in the Terminal.

```
> cd ~
> lualatex Test
```

This resulted in the file `~/Test.pdf` being created. When opened in a PDF viewer, the file displayed as follows. (I screenshot only the relevant part of the display.)

[image: A tabularray's cmd key]

This display is as was desired. However, it raised a couple questions in my mind.

**Questions**

1. The `\bfseries` command takes no arguments, whereas the `\fbox` command takes a single mandatory argument. How does `tabularray` know the syntax needed to invoke each command?
2. More generally, what values can the `cmd` key be assigned, and how is this value used by `tabularray`?

Comment: `\bfseries` is a font changing command without arguments, changing only the current font series, not the family, shape etc. for the following text without adding a group or similar. (If you want to change the font only for text inside an argument use `\textbf{...}`.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: you get the equivalent of specifying

```
Hello, world!&\bseries{Hello, world!}&\fbox{Hello, world!}
```

The command `\bfseries` takes no argument, but this is inconsequential.

What commands can you specify? All that take either no argument or one.